$10$ balls placed in five urns. Expected value of the number of empty urns and expected value of number of these urns with exactly one ball in them
There are $10$ balls placed in five urns, for each ball the probability of being in urn number $j$ is $p_j$ (where: $p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 + p_5 = 1$). Calculate the expected value of the number of empty urns and the expected value of the number of these urns with exactly one ball in them.

Expected value of the number of empty urns.
Let $X_j$ be the indicator variable that equals $1$ if urn $j$ is empty and $0$ otherwise.
The total number of empty urns $X$ is given by: $X = X_1​ + X_2​ + X_3 ​+ X_4​ + X_5$

Urn $j$ is empty if none of the $10$ balls are placed in it.
Each ball is independently placed in urn $j$ with probability $p_j$​, so the probability that a single ball is not placed in urn $j$ is $1−p_j$​.

Since the placements are independent, the probability that all $10$ balls are not placed in urn $j$ is: $\mathbb{P}(X_j​=1)=(1−p_j​)$
The expected value of the indicator variable $X_j$​ is: $\mathbb{E}[X_j​] = \mathbb{P}(X_j ​= 1) = (1 − p_j​)$
By the linearity of expectation, the expected value of the total number of empty urns $X$ is:
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X1​+X2​+X3​+X4​+X5​] = \mathbb{E}[X1​] + \mathbb{E}[X2​] + \mathbb{E}[X3​] + \mathbb{E}[X4​] + \mathbb{E}[X5​]$$
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = (1−p_1​)^{10} + (1−p2_​)^{10} + (1−p_3​)^{10} + (1−p_4​)^{10} + (1−p_5​)^{10}$$

Expected value of the number of these urns with exactly one ball in them.
Let $Y_j​$ be the indicator variable that equals $1$ if urn $j$ contains exactly one ball and $0$ otherwise.
The total number of urns with exactly one ball $Y$ is given by: $Y = Y_1 + Y_2 ​+ Y_3 ​+ Y_4 ​+ Y_5$

Urn $j$ contains exactly one ball if exactly one of the $10$ balls is placed in it, and the remaining $9$ balls are placed in other urns.
The probability that a specific ball is placed in urn $j$ is $p_j$​.
The probability that the remaining $9$ balls are not placed in urn $j$ is $(1−p_j​)^9$.

There are $10$ different balls that could be the one placed in urn $j$. Therefore, the probability that urn $j$ contains exactly one ball is:
$$\mathbb{P}(Y_j​=1) = {{10}\choose{1}}p_j​(1−p_j​)^9 = 10p_j​(1−p_j​)^9$$
By the linearity of expectation, the expected value of the total number of urns with exactly one ball $Y$ is:
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[Y_1 ​+ Y_2 ​+ Y_3 ​+ Y_4 ​+ Y_5​] = \mathbb{E}[Y_1​] + \mathbb{E}[Y_2​] + \mathbb{E}[Y_3​] + \mathbb{E}[Y_4​] + \mathbb{E}[Y_5​]$$
Therefore:
$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = 10p_1​(1−p_1​)^9 + 10p_2​(1−p_2​)^9 + 10p_3​(1−p_3​)^9 + 10p_4​(1−p_4​)^9 + 10p_5​(1−p_5​)^9$$

Is my solution correct?

Both your solutions are correct. Linearity of expectation is the key tool here, and you were able to figure that out.
